# Confusion regarding difference in padding results for Anchor and li tags

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the Introduction to CSS Youtube course by Web Dev Simplified. I learnt how display:inline results in padding being applied only to left and right and display:inline-block results in padding applied to top and bottom as well.

[Padding Applied to Anchor Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTJrF.jpg)

```css
.nav {
  background: #333;
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.main-nav a {
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">STORE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Padding Applied to List Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoIgf.jpg)

```css
.nav {
  background: #333;
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">STORE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I expected the opposite results. Can you please explain the difference in the results here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The difference in padding results is caused by the multiple style rules applied to the anchor tags. Also, since `li` elements contain `a` elements it is hard to tell (without developer tools) what kind of padding each of them has.

I've added a `cyan background` to anchor elements and a `dashed red border` to list elements to clearly distinguish them.

#### Original anchor padding

It will be easier to understand if we start with the original padding - when rules for `.main-nav li` and `.main-nav a` are not applied. The anchor elements (cyan background) have all paddings (top, right, bottom, left) set to `0.5em`, so `display: inline-block` **did work** and the padding was applied to top and bottom as well. The list elements (red border) have all paddings set to `0`.

```css
.nav {
  background: #333;
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: darkcyan;
}

.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">STORE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### Extra padding applied to anchors

Once `.main-nav a` is applied it overwrites the original `.nav a` rule and the anchor padding changes completely to `top: 0, right: 5%, bottom: 0, left: 5%`. For the list elements all paddings remain `0`.

```css
.nav {
  background: #333;
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: darkcyan;
}

.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.main-nav a {
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">STORE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### Padding applied to list elements

Once `.main-nav li` is applied it sets the padding for list elements to `top: 0, right: 5%, bottom: 0, left: 5%`. But the anchor elements, without an extra rule, have their all original paddings (*top, right, bottom, left*): `0.5em`.

Visually `padding-left` and `padding-right` values of anchors and list tags add up and the space between them becomes bigger. But with backgrounds and borders it's easy to see an actual padding of each element.

```css
.nav {
  background: #333;
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: darkcyan;
}

.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">STORE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```